# how can i query the record so that i can display them each month wise

Tags: sql

I have no. of records in my amount table and each record saved with date in "created" column.
But now I want to display those records with each month wise and amount must be display as sum of amount for each month.
Like
for the month of
2014-05-01       amount   200 rs. And for the month of 2014-06-01 500rs. like so on

Comment: You really need to provide your field names and what database you are using. Date syntax is very different across databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),PRICE INT,CREATEDDATE DATE)

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
(100,'2015-09-17'),
(200,'2015-09-17'),
(300,'2015-08-17'),
(400,'2015-08-17'),
(500,'2015-08-17'),
(600,'2015-07-17')

SELECT MONTH(CREATEDDATE),YEAR(CREATEDDATE),SUM(PRICE)
FROM TEST
GROUP BY MONTH(CREATEDDATE),YEAR(CREATEDDATE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
select Datepart(month,CreateDate),Sum(Amount)
From Tablename
Group by Datepart(month,CreateDate)
```